# C# listing user input in generic list

Tags: c#, visual-studio

So, I am working on C# to improve myself. I was working on generic list and I just tried to Ask the user two choices. 1 is showing the student list and 2- is adding a student to the list(Id is auto generated, user just giving the name). When i run the code the list is always empty. Where am I douing wrong can you guys help?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AddStudent addStudent = new AddStudent();
        
        PrintStudentsList printStudentsList = new PrintStudentsList();
        int choice;
        
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("1-See the student list\n2-Add a student to the list\n3-Exit");
            choice = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    
            if (choice == 1)
            {
                printStudentsList.PrintStudents();
            }
            else if (choice == 2)
            {
                Console.Write("Enter the Name of the Student please: ");
                string studentName = Console.ReadLine();
                        
                addStudent.Add(studentName);
            }
            else if (choice==3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exiting from the program");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You entered a wrong choice, please try again...");
            }
        } 
        while (choice!=3); 
    
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
    
    
class AddStudent
{
    private List<Students> students = new List<Students>();
    
    public List<Students>GetList()
    {
        return students;
    }
    
    private string _studentName;
             
    //public AddStudent(String studentName)
    //{
    //    _studentName = studentName;
    //}
    
    public void Add(string studentName)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int idNum = rnd.Next(1, 100);
        
        students.Add(
            new Students {Id =idNum, Name = studentName});
        }
    }
    
    class PrintStudentsList
    {
        private AddStudent addStudent = new AddStudent();
        
        public void PrintStudents()
        {
            addStudent.GetList();
            if (addStudent.GetList().Count==0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine( new EmptyListException("Student List is Empty!!!"));
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var student in addStudent.GetList())
                {
                    Console.Write(student);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    class EmptyListException:Exception
    {
        public EmptyListException(string Message):base(Message)
        {
        }
    }
    
    class Students
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: because the list in the class `PrintStudentList` is an empty list and has nothing to do with the generated one in the main : `private AddStudent addStudent = new AddStudent();`

Comment: Do not create and store an `AddStudent` list inside `PrintStudentsList`. Instead, pass the existing `addStudent` variable to `PrintStudents` in `PrintStudentsList` as a parameter: `public void PrintStudents(AddStudent addStudent) ...` and then call `printStudentsList.PrintStudents(addStudent);`

Comment: Thank you guys, that is so right, solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your attempt looked a bit like spaghetti code, so I took the freedom and rewrote it a bit. There were also a couple of issues. I added a couple of comments for further explanation.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // Constructors are better for the programmer, because he knows what variables are required
    // And with this one, a stundent will always have a name and an id
    public Student(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        Id = Program.rnd.Next(1, 100);
    }

    // Important, otherwise Console.WriteLine(student) only outputs "object"
    public override string ToString()
    {
        string result = $"Id: {Id} Name: {Name}";
        return result;
    }
}

public class StudentList
{
    List<Student> students;

    public StudentList()
    {
        students = new List<Student>();
    }
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // Hide the default constructor, because otherwise one might forget setting the name or the id
    private Student()
    {
    }

    // Constructors are better for the programmer, because he knows what variables are required
    // And with this one, a stundent will always have a name and an id
    public Student(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        Id = Program.rnd.Next(1, 100);
    }

    // Important, otherwise Console.WriteLine(student) only outputs "object"
    public override string ToString()
    {
        string result = $"Id: {Id} Name: {Name}";
        return result;
    }
}

public class StudentList
{
    List<Student> list;

    public StudentList()
    {
        list = new List<Student>();
    }

    public List<Student> List
    {
        get
        {
            return list;
        }

        // Dont allow setting the list from outside, so no set here
        //set
        //{
        //    students = value;
        //}
    }

    public void PrintList()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("List of students: ");
        foreach (Student student in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(student);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}

class Program
{
    // Make sure you only create one instance of Random, don't instantiate it whenever you need a new value. Otherwise you risk getting the same results
    public static Random rnd = new Random();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StudentList students = new StudentList();
        int choice;

        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("1-See the student list\n2-Add a student to the list\n3-Exit");

            // Never use .Parse, because it throws exceptions on invalid input
            // choice = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            string input = Console.ReadLine();

            if (int.TryParse(input, out choice) == false)
            {
                // if parsing didn't work, set the choice to any value that is not one of the cases in belows switch statement
                // it will then be handled by the default switch case
                choice = -1345;
            }

            // Switches are easier to read then too many else ifs
            switch (choice)
            {
                case 1:
                    // Don't throw Exceptions when you don't have to, you could do something like this instead
                    if (students.List.Count == 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("There are no students");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        students.PrintList();
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Student student = GetStudent();
                    students.List.Add(student);
                    break;
                // Nothing to do here, it's just to prevent entering the default case
                case 3:
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("You entered a wrong choice, please try again...");
                    break;
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        } while (choice != 3);
        Console.WriteLine("Exiting from the program");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static Student GetStudent()
    {
        Console.Write("Enter the Name of the Student please: ");
        string studentName = Console.ReadLine();

        Student student = new Student(studentName);
        return student;
    }
}
```

Comment: In C#, once you declare another constructor with parameters, no default constructor is created by default. You must declare the default constructor explicitly, if you need some and other constructors are declared.

Comment: Ok, forgot about that, I'll remove it

Comment: Thank you for another solution, I didn't know the toString override part, that saved me. Is my coding so bad? I'm curious because you said that your code looked a bit Spaghetti code. I am open to any advice, thank you again :)

Comment: It's not that bad, it's beginners code, that happens to all of us in the beginning. You've got two examples on how to do it, mine and the one from Dan Csharpster. Just compare them to your approach and you will see the difference. Our's are more lightweight, not that complicated. Dan's version is even stripped down to the minimum, very lightweight.

Comment: Got it  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Good work, @AdrAs!  I made a few tweaks for another perspective.  I think we can skip the StudentList class altogether since hiding the set wasn't a requirement I think.  Then I made the PrintList into an extension method.

Working fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bZkhyZ).

And the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;       

public class Program
{
    // Make sure you only create one instance of Random, don't instantiate it whenever you need a new value. Otherwise you risk getting the same results
    public static Random rnd = new Random();

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var students = new List<Student>();
        int choice;

        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("1-See the student list\n2-Add a student to the list\n3-Exit");

            // Never use .Parse, because it throws exceptions on invalid input
            // choice = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            string input = Console.ReadLine();

            if (int.TryParse(input, out choice) == false)
            {
                // if parsing didn't work, set the choice to any value that is not one of the cases in belows switch statement
                // it will then be handled by the default switch case
                choice = -1345;
            }

            // Switches are easier to read then too many else ifs
            switch (choice)
            {
                case 1:
                    // Don't throw Exceptions when you don't have to, you could do something like this instead
                    if (students.Count == 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("There are no students");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        students.PrintList();
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Student student = GetStudent();
                    students.Add(student);
                    break;
                // Nothing to do here, it's just to prevent entering the default case
                case 3:
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("You entered a wrong choice, please try again...");
                    break;
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        } while (choice != 3);
        Console.WriteLine("Exiting from the program");

        
    }

    private static Student GetStudent()
    {
        Console.Write("Enter the Name of the Student please: ");
        string studentName = Console.ReadLine();

        Student student = new Student(studentName);
        return student;
    }
}

public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // Hide the default constructor, because otherwise one might forget setting the name or the id
    private Student()
    {
    }

    // Constructors are better for the programmer, because he knows what variables are required
    // And with this one, a stundent will always have a name and an id
    public Student(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        Id = Program.rnd.Next(1, 100);
    }

    // Important, otherwise Console.WriteLine(student) only outputs "object"
    public override string ToString()
    {
        //string result = $"Id: {Id} Name: {Name}";
        string result = String.Format("Id: {0} Name: {1}", Id, Name);
        return result;
    }
}

public static class StudentListExtensions
{
    public static void PrintList(this List<Student> list)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nList of students: ");
        foreach (Student student in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(student);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    
    class Program
    {
        private static List<Students> studentsList = new List<Students>();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            
            int choice;

            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("1-See the student list\n2-Add a student to the list\n3-Exit");
                choice = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                if (choice == 1)
                {
                    PrintStudents();
                }

                else if (choice == 2)
                {
                    Console.Write("Enter the Name of the Student please: ");
                    string studentName = Console.ReadLine();

                   Add(studentName);

                }
                else if (choice == 3)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Exiting from the program");

                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You entered a wrong choice, please try again...");
                }
            } while (choice != 3);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void Add(string studentName)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int idNum = rnd.Next(1, 100);

            studentsList.Add(
                new Students { Id = idNum, Name = studentName });
        }

        static void PrintStudents()
        {
            
            if (studentsList.Count == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(new EmptyListException("Student List is Empty!!!"));

            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var student in studentsList)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine($"student Number:{student.Id} StudentName:{student.Name}");
                }
            }

        }

    }


    



    class EmptyListException : Exception
    {
        public EmptyListException(string Message) : base(Message)
        {

        }

    }

    class Students
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

}
```